# Getting bigger resolution profile image from Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to get user's profile image from the Twitter API in nodeJS. I actually manage to do it but it comes with a really low resolution. Twitter is an npm package and 'control' contains the Oauth credentials. This is the code:

```
var client = new twitter(control);

app.get('/main', function(req, res){
  client.get('account/verify_credentials', function(error, params) {
  if(error) throw error;
  username = params.screen_name;
  name = params.name;
  image = params.profile_image_url;
  res.render("index.ejs", {username: username, name: name, image: image});
  });
});
```

How can I change the request so that it would be in a similar form to get a better resolution image.

Comment: There's some info on this on their API docs: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/user-profile-images-and-banners

Comment: Yeah, however I don't understand the routes they are providing and I don't know if it matches the app structure that I am sticking to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are all profile images you can get :

```
// NORMAL
// http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png
image = params.profile_image_url;

// BIGGER
// http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_bigger.png
image = params.profile_image_url.replace(/_normal\./, '_bigger.');

// MINI
// http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_mini.png
image = params.profile_image_url.replace(/_normal\./, '_mini.');

// ORIGINAL
// http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile.png
image = params.profile_image_url.replace(/_normal\./, '.');
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I modified the URL this way, thank you!